# How do I find max date for matching entities by entity.ids using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

How do I use linq to find the last cat status for matching cat ids using mvc 4, ef5, and linq?

Example doesn't currently work right b/c max doesn't allow for datetime only ints, dec, etc...   I would have to break this up into like at least 7 or 8 max checks for each part of a date time like years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds, etc... but am searching for a better way than this:

```
cat.CatStatuses = dbCat.CatStatuses.Where(catstatus => catstatus.id == catstatus.id).Where(catstatus => catstatus.date == (dbCat.CatStatuses.Max(catstatus.date)));
```

Is there a better more efficient way to do this in linq, mvc 4, and entity framework?  I was trying to use the func statement to make this work better.

Cat status might be like:
"lay down", "get up", "growl", "meow", "scratch master", "climb", "dine", "catch mouse"

Cat status date is the date and time the status occurred.

My question is how do I get last cat status by the max cat status date in the most efficient manner using linq in an ef5 environment?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
dbCat.CatStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.date).Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//where the variable catStatusId contains the value of the id you want.
cat.CatStatuses = dbCat.CatStatuses.Where(catstatus => catstatus.id == catStatusId).OrderByDescending(catstatus=>catstatus.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Jonni's suggestion was good, however, you should reduce the data you select like so:

```
dbCat.CatStatuses =
    dbCat.CatStatuses.Where(cs => cs.id == catStatusId)
        .OrderByDescending(cs => cs.Date)
        .Select(cs => cs.status)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is more or less equivalent to:

```
select top(1)
    status
from DbCat.dbo.CatStatuses cs
where cs.id == @catStatusId
order by cs.Date desc
```

or perhaps more like:

```
select top(1)
    status
    from
    (
        select status, date
        from DbCat.dbo.CatStatuses cs
        where cs.id == @catStatusId
        order by cs.date desc
    ) x
```

Which is efficient if you have the right indexes.